# How to std::tie to unpack results of std::minmax_element?

Tags: c++11

I have a container **v** of elements of type **T**, to which I apply std::minmax_element, like so:

```
auto min_max = std::minmax_element(v.begin, v.end);
auto min = min_max.first;
auto max = min_max.second;
```

I would like to unpack the results of std::minmax_element with std::tie, but I can't figure the type for the declaration:

```
*type?* first_it, last_it;
std::tie(first_it, last_it) = std::minmax_element(v.begin, v.end);
```

What would be the type of *first_it* and *last_it*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::minmax_element` returns a pair of `iterator` as member type of passed a container, so for vector it is `vector<T>::iterator`:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,2,3};
decltype(v)::iterator first_it, last_it; // or vector<int>::iterator 
std::tie(first_it,last_it) = std::minmax_element(v.begin(), v.end());
```

If you change for using `cbegin/cend`, you have to change iterator type to `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

```
auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(v.begin, v.end);
```